# Successively get content of the file

Tags: java

how can i get successively the content of each files, what i have is only get the content of one file with all file names from folder:

```
  public static List<Objekt> run() throws IOException {  

    String path2 = "/files";  

    File folder = new File(path2);  

    listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();  

    for (File f : listOfFiles) {  

        for (int k = 0; k < listOfFiles.length; k++) {  

            if (listOfFiles[k].isFile()) {  

                files = listOfFiles[k].getName().replace(".csv", "");  


                    System.out.println(files);  



            }  

            BufferedReader br = null;  

            String line = "";  

            String obname = files.toString();  

            String csvSplitBy = ";";  

            Objekt objekt = null;  

            String[] hdr = null;  

            int l_count = 0;  

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));  

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  

                if (l_count == 0) {  

                    hdr = line.split(csvSplitBy);  

                }
          for(int l=0;l<listOfFiles.length;l++){  
          {  

                String[] temp = line.split(cvsSplitBy);    

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {    

                objekt = new Objekt();    

                objekt.setTimestamp(hdr[i] + "\t" + temp[0] + "\t"    
                        + temp[i] + "\t" + obname+ "\n");    

                lines.add(objekt);    

            }    

            System.out.println(lines);    

        }    


        l_count++;    

    }    

   br.close();    

return lines; 
}
```

I become only one content of first file and other filenames also with content of the first file but without their content.

Comment: Is this the same question you asked [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23999940/2970947)? It wasn't very clear then either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File file = new File("C:\\DirectoryName");
File[] filesInDir = file.listFiles();
```

Now all the files in the `C:\DirectoryName` are in the `filesInDir[]`.

Then, for the content in the first you can use: filesInDir[0] or loop to verify if the name matches what you call the first file. Then get its contents.